# angularjs responding to redirect from asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am returing in aps.net mvc a redirect url
like :

```
   public ActionResult GetConsent(string redirectUri = null)
        {
         Redirect("Result.com");
        }
```

but in response in angularjs i could not read this link

```
   this.getconsent = function () {
        $http.get('Test/Integration/').success(function (data) {
            if (data.url != null) {
                var win = window.open(data.url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            }
        });
```

however, when i call for result i could not opent the link in angular cause the error come: Failed to load"Result.com" from "Result.com"
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7869' is therefore not allowed access.
any help to open link in angularjs?

Comment: Did you check with break point? I hope your service does not invoked

Comment: i checked it return the result but when result come it resonse not with link but with this error

Comment: Do you know what CORS is?

Comment: CORS is your browser saying "I'm not going to that URL because it is different that the URL that you loaded this page from. The only way to disable this is on the server-side. You must setup your ASP.NET MVC app to allow the page to be re-directed to "Result.com" specifically, or allow a wildcard(*), but this is not recommended